# How does the JS scope of these blocks work?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, lexical-closures

Can anyone explain why the following produces 1,2 and the other produces 5? Should they not both produce 5?

```
//produces 1,2
(function () {

    var a = [5];

    function bar() {
        if (!a) {
          var a = [1, 2];
        }
        console.log(a.join());
    }

    bar();

})();
```

Based on reading some articles about JS closure, I expect them both to produce 5. Can't seem to find an article anywhere that would give some insight as to why the first block produces otherwise.

```
//produces 5
(function () {

    var a = [5];

    function bar() {
        if (a) {
          console.log(a.join());
        }
        else {
          console.log([1, 2].join())
        }
    }

    bar();

})();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid problems like this, and stop worrying about hoisting, by just declaring your variables at the top of the function, as best practices dictate.

Comment: @torazaburo I heard of this but could u provide a source?

Comment: @jkris You could start here: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations

Comment: @torazaburo Crockford, nice! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to javascripts [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), this code:

```
(function () {
    var a = [5];
    function bar() {
        if (!a) {
          var a = [1, 2];
        }
        console.log(a.join());
    }
    bar();
})();
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
(function () {
    var a = [5];
    function bar() {
        var a; // a === undefined at this point
        if (!a) {
          a = [1, 2];
        }
        console.log(a.join());
    }
    bar();
})();
```

So you can see, `a` will indeed be `falsey` (i.e. !a === true) when the if condition is tested

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. I read some other docs and got the idea now. Need only understand the following statement and the confusion goes away. "Hoisting is the mechanism of moving the variables and functions declaration to the top of the function scope." https://rainsoft.io/javascript-hoisting-in-details/

Comment: hoisting has absolutely nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: what is your damage @BekimBacaj?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid re-declaring `var a = [1, 2];` and just initialize as `a = [1, 2];` in your top function. Like @Jaromanda explained the variable is hoisted in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that should be avoided. I just didn't know this was the very reason why and the terminology behind it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Jeromanda X has given the right answer, it's due to [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), I'd just like to add on to illustrate better.

Your 2 codes blocks are different in that you created a new variable in one and did not in the other. To be fair you should change code block #2 to the following

```
//produces [1,2] now
(function () {

  var a = [5];

  function bar() {
      if (a) {
        console.log(a.join());
      }
      else {
        var a = [1,2];
        console.log(a.join())
      }
  }

  bar();

})();
```

If you had omitted `var` in both code blocks you wouldn't have run into this scoping problem both code blocks would have produced `5`

Answer (score -2):

We know that every function creates its own context and can have its own local variables and things.

We therefore presume that writing `var a = [5]` , in the context of top most function context, will make it available and accessible by the context of any new nested functions we may write.

And this is where we encounter a behavior which is most probably 'undocumented' as well as 'unexpected'.

The 1at example of the op

```
function bar(){
    if(!a) { 
           var a = [1,2];
          }
    console.log(a);
    }
>> 1,2
```

has it return a local value of 1,2.
where we can see that the ***if*** conditional of the ***bar*** function ***context*** is treating the host function *variable **a***, as ***undefined*** wherefore it is negating it ***!a*** to ***true***.

Why is that?
A commentator insists in hoisting. But what hoisting?
There's absolutely no interference of a hoisting principle in a final result or behavior in the two versions of the same function at which the only difference is in conditional argument: one checks if 'a' is *false* and the other, if it's *true*.

Hoisting! What hoisting? 
If it were for "hoisting" - the **!a** operation should unmistakably  return ***false*** because of the fact that a is already defined with a *truthy* value on a higher context accessible to any and every lower context functions of the host. But quite the contrary

As a consequence of if(!a [false] ) therefore *true* from conditional return, it is allowing the execution of a new declaration of ***a*** variable with the same name using the var key, as if it's out of reach or doesn't exist in a  higher scope at all.

And it shouldn't.  But it should.

Now trying the same thing without the negation of the if argument in conditional, we'll get an error and an assignment failure as in:

```
 function bar(){
    if(a) { 
           var a = [1,2];
          }
    console.log(a);
    }
>> undefined
```

[!same as when using if(!!a) ]
We've changed nothing except that now we are asking if a is true so that we can create a new local 'a' variable with value [1,2];

**What is going on?!** 
The ***if*** conditional which is in explicit need for the ***a*** argument to be *true* in order to proceed is **looking up** and "climbing it down" to the local context of the *function **bar***.

For some reason it is handled as an attempt to re-declare the variable of a host function and refusing to initialize and assign a value to new variable with the same name in a local context. That's a confusion because of the conditional which now refers to the host variable it is refusing to declare and assign a value to a local a.

However, on the console log a local variable a is being returned and it is ***undefined***.

Which is unexpected; contradictory; defiant but seemingly correct!
It is correct because the local **a** variable was initialized but didn't get a value correctly to begin with. We've tried to re-declare the one from the higher context, and it wasn't allowed.

The only good thing is - the behavior appears to be uniform across browsers.

Comment: *allow the execution of the following declarations* No, declarations are not executed sequentially; they are hoisted, as other answers have made clear.

Comment: yes they are, the if condition tests if variable "a" is defined e.g. true and because var a is already true the conditional allows for the local `var a = [1, 2];` to be executed.

Comment: I don't think were talking about the same issue here

Comment: I think I'll have to rewrite my answer because the op is asking something something else but wrote two blocks of code that don't correspond in logic.

Comment: @JaromandaX - I just tested the 1st examaple in my FF console and I've encountered an error - which is completely unexpected - test this:  `(function () {
    var a = [5];
    function bar() {
        if (a) {
          var a = [1, 2];
        }
        console.log(a.join());
    }
    bar();
})();`

What do you think about that?

Comment: @JaromandaX, see if I managed to explain it in my revision of the previous answer. Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX there's no `join()` at my emphasis example explanation  at all.

Comment: And no @JaromandaX I understood "hoisting" when it didn't even have a name :)